Deleted question with positive score and answer
This question has a 7-0 votes balance, and my answer to it got 29 upvotes.
Nevertheless it has been deleted by Community, which I suspect means in this case when the user was deleted it carried the post down with them.
Was this supposed to happen?

Yes, this was supposed to happen. The user in question violated the rules of the site in multiple ways, including ways which warrant removing their posts.
If you think the question has enduring value, feel free to post and self-answer a similar question.
